# Why doesn't evaluate find a result?

Tags: javascript, xml

I am loading an xml document as a string. I have selected a particular childNode and would like to test whether it contains any nodes named "block".

```
<block xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" type="task" id="c77e2dae-236d-4b22-8484-f90dd0f74ce4" x="88" y="13">
    <statement name="script">
        <block type="nlsql" id="691fc997-f306-40fe-9344-793f18ff8730"></block>
    </statement>
</block>
```

I wanted to use document.evaluate so I tried this

```
blocks = elm.ownerDocument.evaluate('.//block', elm, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
```

but I get no results.
In this case I would prefer not to use jQuery however, it does give me a result using

```
$(elm).find('block').addBack('block')
```

Why does jQuery work when evaluate won't?

Comment: Probably something to do with your namespace resolver being null. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript

Comment: @Quentin I tried your suggestion but it didn't change the result. I used nsResolver = document.createNSResolver( elm.ownerDocument) and then passed that in. I wouldn't have thought it would matter as I didn't think that any of the nodes are using namespaces.

Comment: "I didn't think that any of the nodes are using namespaces" — *`<block xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`* — the namespace is a bit hard to miss!

Comment: @Quentin fair call. What I meant was that I wasn't using namespaces in the node names. I didn't realize that default namespaces would require a namespace resolver. However, it still doesn't work with the resolver included.